# Mouse in Maze - Stacks (but count steps also)

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am reading Adam Drozdek's book on DSA, and in solving the mouse in maze problem, he is using stacks. But how would I (if i wanted) count the number of steps the rat takes ? Because according to his stack solution , false positive neighbors (ie. the neigbors that failed to reach destination) also get marked, and there is no backtracking which unmarks these cells. Pls help me. Pls.

EDIT: his algorithm

```
exitMaze ()
    while currentCell is not exitCell
        mark currentCell as visited;
        push unvisited neighbors of currentCell onto the stack
        if stack is empty
             failure;
        else pop off a cell from the stack and make it currentCell
    success;
```

This way the maze will be filled with a path of X's starting from Rat's initial point to exit point. But it will also be filled with 'X's on the tried and failed paths. So how do i count the number of steps in the path ?

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you without showing a lot more detail about the algorithm, and your implementation of it (unless they happen to have read the same book recently, I suppose). Please add more to your question, and think about what some random person online would need to know to understand your problem.

Comment: @BoBTFish thank you for reading and replying this. I just edited it. maybe it can provide more clarity to my question.

Comment: It seems to me the easiest way to do this is to put more information into your stack object: the next cell *and* the path that got there. Then when you pop that object  your path is the previous path and the new cell. When you pop a position that is the exit, you have the full path. If you only need the count, you can store that instead of the path, and add one to it each time you push a new cell.

Comment: BoBTFish' suggestion of adding the distance is correct but note that this algorithm does not necessarily find the shortest path. If there are multiple paths through the maze with different lengths, the order of the unvisited neighbors in `push unvisited neighbors of currentCell onto the stack` determines which of those lengths you will get out. Depending on your requirements, that may or may not make sense. If you want to know the shortest path you'll need a different algorithm.

Comment: Thanks @BoBTFish , i just realized that AFTER solving the maze, i can reapply the same algorithm on the load of 'X's, because as you said , its a "path", and a path is 1 straight line. That means at any point of the path, it cannot bifurcate or trifurcate. if it does, then i push the sub-paths onto a path stack and pop them until i reach destination. This way i will achieve an array of cells that marks the path. and sizeof(array) will give me "count" or the steps required.

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele Ah i see. Yes i think different algorithm will be needed for that, but i haven't reached that chapter yet haha, but when i do , it will become more interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little change to the algorithm, you're left at the end with the path on the stack:

```
exitMaze ()
    push start cell on the stack
    while stack is not empty
        let currentCell = top cell on the stack
        mark currentCell as visited; //it might already be marked, but that's OK
        if currentCell is exitCell
            success. Path is on the stack;
        else if currentCell has an unvisited neighbor
            push an unvisited neighbor on the stack
        else
            pop a cell off the stack
    failure;
```